# Convert C array literal to work in C++ constructor?

Tags: c++, c

I have some C code that I'm trying to convert/wrap into a C++ class. I ran into some C literal arrays(correct me if I'm calling them wrong) and I'm not sure how to initialize them in the C++ constructor since I don't think you can do literals, which I think are compile time specific, to something that is runtime specific.

Should I just explicitly define the array to be of a certain size and just do a strcpy, or some such, of the literal to the array in the constructor?

```
char sysUpTime[] = {1,3,6,1,2,1,1,3,0};
```

Comment: If you are using **C++11** then you have _initializer-lists_, otherwise there is not really much you can do. Perhaps switch them to `boost|std::array`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative to initializer lists or string manipulation, you could use something like the following (if you really wanted to):

```
struct Wrapper
{
    template <size_t N>
    Wrapper(const char(&arr)[N]) : vec(arr, arr+N) { }

    vector<char> vec;
};
```

I've left everything public due to chronic laziness on my part :).  You can then initialise like this:

```
    char foo[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    Wrapper bar(foo);

    copy(bar.vec.begin(), bar.vec.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, ", "));
```

Comment: Nice I submitted and deleted an answer passing the size along with the array to the constructor, this is much nicer. Didn't know the size could be deduced using templates like that :)

Answer (score 1):

Could just use std::string to store OID then initialize it in `member initializer list` for example:

```
#include <string>
class Wrapper
{
public:
  Wrapper() : sysUpTime("1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0") { }
private:
  std::string sysUpTime;
};
```

Or use C++11 [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

```
class Wrapper
{
public:
  Wrapper() : sysUpTime{{1,3,6,1,2,1,1,3,0}} { }

public:
  std::array<char, 10> sysUpTime;
};
```

Comment: Thank you @Billz. Is `Wrapper() : ...` shorthand for the constructor? I'm getting myself back up to speed in C++ and I'm not familiar with that syntax.

Comment: @EhevuTov yes, between between :`{ is called member initializer list

Comment: @EhevuTov That's normal syntax squished onto a single line

Comment: Ah, thanks. I don't think the C++ I learned 18 years ago had that or I just didn't learn it that far. Now C++ has things like lambda functions.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem when passing different size c-style arrays to a constructor is that you must pass the size along with it. Here's an example of putting the array into a member vector:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Test
{
  std::vector<char> sysUpTime;

  Test(const char sysUpTime[], size_t size) :
    sysUpTime(sysUpTime, sysUpTime + size)
  { }
};


int main()
{
  const char sysUpTime[] = {1,2,3,4,5};

  Test test(sysUpTime, sizeof(sysUpTime) / sizeof(char));
}
```

Unfortunately I know of no way to do this without using a dynamic array (vector), aside from using templates which means that you'll get a separate class instantiated for each and every change in the size of your array.

Comment: msandiford's answer uses a much nicer way of passing the size to the constructor.